# Custom command when hibernating not running

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, suspend

I need to run a custom command before the hibernation in Debian Buster. The [documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation) says to place script to directory /etc/pm/sleep.d.
I creates the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "`date` script started" >> scriptStarted.txt

case "$1" in
        hibernate|suspend)
                /home/<user-name>/scripts/killProcess.sh

                ;;
        thaw|resume)
                ;;
        *) exit $NA
                ;;
esac
```

The problem is that the script is not executed.

I also tried directory /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/ but issue is the same.

Comment: Does the script have the execute permission bit set?

Comment: Yes, it does (thanks to `chmod +x`). I ran it many times and it works.

Comment: Do you really want to store the startup message in `/scriptStarted.txt` or whatever `$PWD` is ? Does `/home/<user-name>/scripts/killProcess.sh` use absolute paths? Depend on environment  variables set in your environment but not in the Power Management environment?

Comment: What do you mean by "I ran it many times and it worked"? Repeated lid flaps? Close-Open is 1 flap. Do you wait before opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Debian Buster uses systemd, not pm.

When I put a script to /lib/systemd/system-sleep it was executed before the system was suspended.

```
#!/bin/sh 

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin 

case "$1" in 
   pre) 
           echo "`date` pre suspending executed" >> /home/<user-name>/scripts/execution.log
           #code execution BEFORE sleeping/hibernating/suspending 
   ;; 
   post) 
           #code execution AFTER resuming 
   ;; 
esac 

exit 0
```

However, in the case of hibernation this solution still didn’t work. The script was not run when the system was hibernating.

Finally I created a custom service. I placed file my-hibernate.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system:

```
[Unit] 
Description=Some description 
Before=hibernate.target 
StopWhenUnneeded=yes 

[Service] 
Type=oneshot 
RemainAfterExit=yes 
ExecStart=/home/<user-name>/scripts/my-script.sh 

[Install] 
WantedBy=hibernate.target
```

Next, I enabled the service:

```
sudo systemctl enable my-hibernate.service
```

After these steps the custom script is executed before the hibernation.